# dynamically aggregate data based on user input and create KML to be displayed on map

Tags: google-maps, google-fusion-tables

I want to dynamically aggregate data based on user input (basically firing a sql on my database ) and create a dynamic KML file out of that and display it on google map using their java script API .

How can i achieve this .

Note :All of my data is either on private cloud or in house ,initially i thought of exporting some of the data of my use (for aggregation purpose) to fusion but got lost on how to achieve my end target .

Answer (score 1):

You can import data to Google Fusion Tables (you have to go to Google Drive, and activate Fusion Tables addon, then can create new table object), and then can export it as KML which can be displayed in Google maps.